# android.Android() on QPython error

Tags: android, python, sl4a, qpython

I'm running SL4A Python 2.6.2 interpreter. This code works without problem:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
```

But when I'm running QPython 2.7.2 interpreter on the same machine, the same code gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Android'
```

Answer (score 6):

import `androidhelper`  instead.

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
```